# Why does the anonymous function lose the object scope?

Tags: javascript

Should the anonymous function/closure not retain the scope of the object where it was created?

```
var myObject = {
foo: "bar",
func: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
    console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    (function() {
        console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
    }());
}
};
myObject.func();
```

This way produces the same result.

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
        console.log("outer func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        return function() {
            console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
            console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
        };
    }
};
myObject.func()();
```

// output

```
outer func:  this.foo = bar
outer func:  self.foo = bar
inner func:  this.foo = undefined
inner func:  self.foo = bar
```

Comment: There seems to be more to it than just "this" based on @Josh Beam's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just a core concept of JavaScript (specifically ECMAScript5). Anonymous functions, especially in a closure, don't retain the context.

You can do something like this:

```
(function() {
    console.log("inner func:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
    console.log("inner func:  self.foo = " + self.foo);
}).call(this);
```

That's since you're actually calling the function. If you were passing in a callback, you might use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) instead.

If you're using ECMAScript6, you can use arrow functions to retain the context of an anonymous callback:

```
(() => {
  // `this` retains the context of its parent context
});
```

Comment: Thanks josh. After playing a bit around with the concept i got it now. Do you have a reference where i can dig deeper into the matter.

Comment: @alknows no problem, glad it was helpful :) This is an article I read a long time ago and that I think has some decent content: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/. Also, I would suggest reading the `Function.prototype.bind` page in full that I linked in the answer, and also check out this link that explains arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. Let me know if you nee any other resources, I'll be happy to help!